# Iterating pandas frame fails

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to python.  I recently downloaded this project which is used to analyze stock trends on reddit.  The project is located [here:](https://github.com/GonVas/tickerrain)

They have code in the Procces.py

```
def calculate_df(df):
    data_df = df.filter(['tickers', 'score', 'sentiment'])

    tickers_processed = pd.DataFrame(df.tickers.explode().value_counts())
    tickers_processed = tickers_processed.rename(columns = {'tickers':'counts'})

    tickers_processed['score'] = 0.0
    tickers_processed['sentiment'] = 0.0

    for idx, row_tick in enumerate(tickers_processed.iloc):
```

I'm getting an error when I try to enumerate the `tickers_processed.iloc`

> Exception has occurred: NotImplementedError
> ix is not iterable

Stack track:

> File "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\NLP\trading-bot-base\tickerrain\process.py", line 113, in calculate_df
> for idx, row_tick in enumerate(tickers_processed.iloc):
> File "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\NLP\trading-bot-base\tickerrain\process.py", line 152, in processed_df
> return calculate_df(df), calculate_df(df_3), calculate_df(df_1)

I've looked at a few other questions about this, they said to try to do something like this instead:

```
for idx, row_tick in tickers_processed.iloc[::1]
```

I tried this and it didn't work either.  Does anyone know how I can enumerate the iloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `df.iterrows()`

```
for idx, row_tick in tickers_processed.iterrows():
    ...
```

Comment: i don't think you need enumerate there.. 
for idx, row_tick in etickers_processed.iterrows():
should work just fine

Comment: Thanks so much (It might take me a few hours to accept the answer), I'll try this when I get back on the project tonight

Comment: Thanks, I've verified I can pass that error now :)